# MySQL Query with variables works only once per connection

Tags: mysql, sql, variables

I have a query for finding out a session based on timestamps and the timedifference to the previous row. The problem is, that the query only works on first execution...

modified query to show the problem:

```
mysql> SELECT channel, time, latitude, longitude, time_diff FROM ( SELECT time, (@prev_time - time) AS time_diff, IF( (@prev_time - time) > 300, @prev_time := 9999999999,@prev_time := time) AS prev_time, latitude, longitude, channel FROM (SELECT @prev_time := 0) AS vars JOIN waypoints WHERE waypoints.channel = 25 ORDER BY time DESC ) AS tmp  ORDER BY time DESC;

+---------+------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| channel | time       | latitude  | longitude | time_diff   |
+---------+------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
|      25 | 1390335836 | 52.051292 |  8.550871 | -1390335836 |
|      25 | 1390335832 | 52.051296 |  8.550889 |           4 |
|      25 | 1390335575 | 52.051300 |  8.550860 |         257 |
|      25 | 1390335571 | 52.051300 |  8.550869 |           4 |
|      25 | 1390335521 | 52.051285 |  8.550858 |          50 |
|      25 | 1390335517 | 52.051277 |  8.550858 |           4 |
|      25 | 1390335081 | 52.051258 |  8.550860 |         436 |
|      25 | 1390334746 | 52.051258 |  8.550877 |  8609665253 |
|      25 | 1390334742 | 52.051224 |  8.550899 |  8609665257 |
+---------+------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT channel, time, latitude, longitude, time_diff FROM ( SELECT time, (@prev_time - time) AS time_diff, IF( (@prev_time - time) > 300, @prev_time := 9999999999,@prev_time := time) AS prev_time, latitude, longitude, channel FROM (SELECT @prev_time := 0) AS vars JOIN waypoints WHERE waypoints.channel = 25 ORDER BY time DESC ) AS tmp  ORDER BY time DESC;

+---------+------------+-----------+-----------+----------------------+
| channel | time       | latitude  | longitude | time_diff            |
+---------+------------+-----------+-----------+----------------------+
|      25 | 1390335836 | 52.051292 |  8.550871 | 18446744072319215780 |
|      25 | 1390335832 | 52.051296 |  8.550889 |           8609664167 |
|      25 | 1390335575 | 52.051300 |  8.550860 |           8609664424 |
|      25 | 1390335571 | 52.051300 |  8.550869 |           8609664428 |
|      25 | 1390335521 | 52.051285 |  8.550858 |           8609664478 |
|      25 | 1390335517 | 52.051277 |  8.550858 |           8609664482 |
|      25 | 1390335081 | 52.051258 |  8.550860 |           8609664918 |
|      25 | 1390334746 | 52.051258 |  8.550877 |           8609665253 |
|      25 | 1390334742 | 52.051224 |  8.550899 |           8609665257 |
+---------+------------+-----------+-----------+----------------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

(in combination of WHERE time_diff < 300 I get on first execution 6 results and in the following executions 0 results)

any ideas?

here the original query;

```
SELECT 
    channel, 
    time, 
    latitude, 
    longitude 
FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        time, 
        (@prev_time - time) AS time_diff, 
        IF( (@prev_time - time) > 300, @prev_time := 9999999999,@prev_time := time) AS prev_time, 
        latitude, 
        longitude, 
        channel 
    FROM 
        waypoints, (SELECT @prev_time := 0) AS vars 
    WHERE waypoints.channel = 25    
    ORDER BY time DESC 
) AS tmp 

WHERE tmp.time_diff < 300 
ORDER BY time DESC
```

here is a dump of the related table: https://gist.github.com/denyskoch/8567707

Comment: I created a fiddle with your dump and query, but it crashes for a bigint overflow. Maybe you could have a look at it ? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/347d71/1

Comment: @Sebas hmm, I dont know why there is an overflow :(

Comment: I tried with mysql v5.1 (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/347d7/2) and there it works. But then the results are stable, they are like the second time you run the query in your env...

Comment: Yeah on v5.1 it works (like my server is) but the result not correct, due to the BIGINT overflow. finally thanks to your fiddle with the error, I could solve it.

Comment: I think I found it too. It seems mysql tried to cast the timediff as signed, which is not possible since you declared the column as unsigned. The engines probably affects the biggest value for a int(10) then... with just going from unsigned to signed it works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/2726f/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to the fiddle of @Sebas (and for bad of mysql v5.1, that dont throw errors on numeric errors) I could solve it:

you can use

```
SET sql_mode = 'NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION';
```

or the better way:

- **make** the `time` field **signed**

The problem is related to  `@prev_time - time` which is something like this: `UNSIGNED - UNSINGED` and results of unsigned devision results in an BIGINT overflow :)